# Extract property values from nested array of objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following nested array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "info": [
            {
                "period": {
                    "start": "2020-01-01",
                    "end": "2020-01-31"
                },
                "info": [
                    {
                        "id": 036,
                        "name": "john",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 037,
                        "name": "inna",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "info": [
            {
                "period": {
                    "start": "2020-01-01",
                    "end": "2020-01-31"
                },
                "info": [
                    {
                        "id": 045,
                        "name": "carl",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 056,
                        "name": "tina",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I want to extract all the values of the "name" property and put them in an array.

Output: `["john", "inna", "carl", "tina"]`.

Comment: And your question/problem is what exactly?

Comment: How to get that output

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
const userNames = [];

data.map(item => {
    return item.info.map(registry => {
        return registry.info.map(user => userNames.push(user.name));
    })
})
```

Output: `["john", "inna", "carl", "tina"]`

Comment: Thanks for the help. This worked even without the return.